# Call JavaScript Function From PHP Script Using jQuery getScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jQuery & web development in general. I'm attempting to use jQuery's ".getScript()" method to load a couple JavaScript scripts that are written in a particular PHP file, but I think I'm missing something. 
(**NOTE:** I noticed several different questions that looked like they had the potential to help me, but none did. If there's one you know of, feel free to point me in that direction. Thanks.)

When I debug this in Firebug it hits the ".getScript()" call & then jumps on to the next line, seemingly without executing.
Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
jQuery.getScript("relative/path/to/script/phpScript.php", function(){
    alert("I'm HERE!");
    setValues(); // JavaScript function that's written by phpScript.php
});
```

In this case, the JavaScript is being generated by the "phpScript.php" file and my "alert()" never gets run, but I'm not sure why. Any ideas?
I did notice that I'm getting some kind of parse error by following a suggestion in another question. I don't know how to resolve that. Here's the code for that:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
      alert('error loading: ' + request.status + "\nevent: "+ event);
      for (var key in request){
          if (request.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              alert(key + " -> " + request[key]);
          }
     }
});
```

BTW, we're running jQuery with "jQuery.noConflict();" set, which is why I'm not using the shorthand "$()" notation.

Here is a snippet from the response body from the GET call in getScript():

```
<html><script type="text/javascript">
function setValues()
    jQuery("#formname").text(window.formNAME);
    jQuery("#Form_Path").text(window.formPATH);
    jQuery("#Form_DB").text(window.formDB);
    jQuery('#pertaining_to').text(window.pertainNAME);
    jQuery("#Pertain_To_ID").text(window.pertainID);
    jQuery("#Form_ID").text(window.formID);
    jQuery("#Field_ID").text(window.fieldName);
}
</script>

<head>
```

Thanks in advance,
-Mark

Comment: does `setValues()` work from the other script at all? Can you post the body of the response you get (from the firebug net panel) when you attempt to `getScript()`?

Comment: @prodigitalson - Yes, it does seem to work. I've moved the portion of the response body from the GET call in getScript() into my question. It's getting something that seems correct, so, it appears that the script should be available.

Answer (score 4):

If you're loading JS scripts, try writing them as discrete functions into a .js file (e.g.: jsscript.js) and then using this HTML line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jsscript.js'></script>
```

Then you can just call the functions themselves without using .getScript().
(Of course, you need to put the above line before the point where you call the scripts.)

That seems like a much cleaner way of doing it than what you're currently attempting.

EDIT: Given your present circumstances (i.e.: a PHP page that generates JS scripts and a PHP page that calls the scripts), maybe you can so something like this?

```
//PHP page that generates the scripts
function gen_script() {
    //JS script generated into $script variable
    return $script;
}

//PHP page that calls the scripts
include ('generate.php');
echo gen_script();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
You're right. This would be easiest. However, the way things are set up the script I'm trying to reference is in a PHP file that generates/writes the script. The file my jQuery method is in is actually a PHP file that is referenced by every other file that has to process any user input. Thus, including it for the whole file will a negative performance impact on the rest of the site. That's why I'm trying to do it with "getScript()".

Comment: I see. Would the new code in my answer account for your situation?

Comment: I tried your new suggestion, but there was no change.
I wonder if I'm attempting to use getScript() in an unsupported way, or in a way it wasn't intended to be used. However, I thought that, as long as the JS was already written, I would have access to it. I guess that's not the case. 
At any rate, I appreciate you trying to help me, though I may have to lay this to rest for a while. 
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you may just edit your phpScript.php file as

```
function setValues(){
  jQuery("#formname").text(window.formNAME);
  jQuery("#Form_Path").text(window.formPATH);
  //...
}
```

That will be OK.